# Decompiling Kubeflow pipeline

Tags: kubeflow

Kubeflow fails with some Python errors when running a compiled pipeline, e.g.

```
  File "<string>", line 135, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 79, in _resolve_arguments
NameError: name 'constants' is not defined
```

Line numbers in error stack do not correspond to the lines in the original pipeline code.

The code in the compiled pipeline (YAML) is hard to parse for a human:

```
 if val != \"true\" and val != \"false\":\n            raise\
        \ ValueError('the value \"%s\" must be true or false' % name)\n\n    def remove_quotes(val):\n\
        \        return val.replace('\"', \"\").replace(\"'\", \"\")\n\n    def resolve_test_data(val):\n\
```

Is there a way to Python code split into lines in a way Kubeflow see it?